# Alternative of the merge_recurse function in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I have long list of several objects but want to merge all these objects into one object. Merge_recurse does what I want but I need to split my list in two lists because it is too long (see below)

```
List_Merge1<-  merge_recurse(list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa[c(0:200)])
List_Merge2<- merge_recurse(list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa[c(201:394)])
List_Merge<- rbind(List_Merge1, List_Merge2)
```

Does somebody know an alternative which allow me to do it in one step? Thanks

Comment: I am now using the melt.list function. `List_Merge1<- melt(list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa)`. However, the names of my columns are different. It is value."name of the column". It would be nice to keep the original names of my columns.

Comment: I had a mistake in my question. I updated it so it might be more clear now.

Comment: For optimization. I had to create subset to get what I want and was wondering if there is more straightforward in R with very long list that the `merge_recurse` cannot handle like the `melt` function but somehow I cannot keep the column names of my input.

Comment: `join_all` works only with dataframe and my input list is SpatialPolygonDf

Comment: `Melt` works well because it merges my list and transform them as dataframe. I just have to find a way to keep the original names of the columns

Comment: You can try with this example `dput(a)
structure(1:24, .Dim = 2:4, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("p", "x", 
"y"), NULL))`. But keep in my mind that my list are SpatialPolygonDf

Comment: Ok. Well never mind. I will just rename in another step my column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer adapted to my data.

```
List_Merge_Def<- melt(list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa)
List_Merge_Def<- List_Merge_Def[,-c(2:7,13:16, 18:29)]
colnames(List_Merge_Def)<- c("ID", "Tile", "UNIQ_ID", "AREA", "D_90_00", "D_00_05", "Def_Bio_2000")
```